# How to merge entire TFS branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a Dev branch and a UA branch. All I want to do is make UA identical to Dev, but after I merged I compared the two branches and there are a ton of differences between the two. What do I have to do?

I tried `tf merge /force /recursive c:\branch\Dev c:\branch\UA` but I get the error **A version or version range must be specified when using the /force option.** I just want the latest version of Dev to be in UA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out that I needed to include `/version:T` in the command. The `T` tells it to use the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click -> merge : select target : ok

Note: if there is no direct parent-child relationship between the two you'll have to browse for the target branch and perform a baseless merge.

Comment: Baseless merge syntax: Tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it without the /force option? I don't think you need it to just do a basic merge. This works for me:

```
cd c:\path\to\team_project
tf merge /recursive dev\v1.0-prod dev\v1.0
```

My branch is inside a dev subfolder (C:\path\to\team_project\dev\v1.0). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the documentation on the merge command.

> /force:  Ignores the merge history and merges the specified changes from
>   the source into the destination, even if some or all these changes
>   have been merged before.

So I'm not sure if you need to use the force flag just to merge from one branch to another.